# In Bounded Force Layout, the linked nodes are going out of rectangle

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to bound the dragged node within the layout.

I have modified the example [Force Dragging III Canvas](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048)  with the  following code :

```
function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x)) ;
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y)) ;
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
}

function dragended() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  //d3.event.subject.fx = null;
  //d3.event.subject.fy = null;
}
```

The above changes allow the nodes to **stick** and the **dragged node to stay within the rectangle**, however, the linked nodes are going out of rectangle.

I was referring to [Bounded Force Layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) example since it is in SVG I am not able to figure out how to stop the linked nodes (connected to the dragged node) going out from the layout.

[image: Screenshot where the linked nodes going out of layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between SVG and canvas here is relatively easy to fix.

In the linked [svg example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492), the ticked function does some logic for each svg element using that element's bound datum - which is an object in the data array:

```
  function tick() {

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
     ...
```

Since we don't have elements to work with, we can just manipulate the original data array:

```
  function ticked() {

    graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
      d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
      d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
    })
...
```

Here's an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/46e300b5f2ad4af350fbd01ffec3e25d) using your drag functions and the original force canvas example.